# Rails 5 Require a dependent gem conditionally in a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5.2

We are writing a gem that includes multiple common gems used in a couple of our apps. We want to be able to have some kind of config to require or not require a certain gems. But the `application.rb` or `enviroment.rb/*rb` is loaded after gems is loaded. So we can not set a config there. The following way works but its not a good idea and I was wondering if there is a cleaner way to do this

bin/rails . (In consuming app)

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

DISABLE_TRANSPORT = true

APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../config/application', __dir__)
require_relative '../config/boot'
require 'rails/commands'
```

Gemfile (In consuming app)

```
gem 'fruit_chain'
```

fruit_chain/lib/fruit_chain.rb   (Our gem)

```
require analytic 
require transport unless defined?(DISABLE_TRANSPORT) && DISABLE_TRANSPORT
require marketing
...

module FruitChain
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand what you want exactly... however, use `require: false` in the Gemfile may help you ?

```
# Gemfile

gem 'my_super_gem', require: false
```

And in an initializer you `require` them:

```
# config/initializer/fruit_chain.rb

require 'my_super_gem'
```

Comment: The `require: false` would work if I am adding dependencies directly in the main app. But we want to do this in a gem that includes multiple gems. In a gem, we add all the dependent gems in the `gemspec` as `spec.add_dependency` then we require the dependent gem from `lib/<gemname>.rb` for the consuming app  .. My question is if there a better way to `opt-out/opt-in` the dependent gems from the gem

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem and have only thought to include the gems explicitly as a responsibility of the app, and then injecting that gem into the parent gem through a configuration, and ensuring they conform to the same interface.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Are you asking a question or providing an answer? Did the attempt you describe solve the problem?